# Give the first six terms of the sequence $a_1 = 1; a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}a_n+1$ and then give the nth term

Tags: sequences-and-series

Calculating the first six terms is quite easy, but how would I work backwards to figure out what $a_n$ would be?

$a_1 = 1; a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}a_n+1$

Solution:

$a_1 = 1$

$a_2 = \frac{3}{2}$

$a_3 = \frac{7}{4}$

$a_4 = \frac{15}{8}$

$a_5 = \frac{31}{16}$

$a_6 = \frac{63}{32}$

Comment: Don't you see a pattern? Consider $2-a_i$ for each $a_i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $_1=1;_{+1}=\frac{1}{2}_{}+1$, we have:

$a_2=\frac{1}{2}_{1}+1 = \frac{1}{2}+1$;

$a_3=\frac{1}{2}_{2}+1=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)+1 = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2}+1$;

$a_4=\frac{1}{2}_{3}+1= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}+1$;

...

So, we conjecture that the general formula is:

$a_n= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-2} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-3}+ \cdots +\frac{1}{2}+1 = \frac{(1/2)^{n}-1}{(1/2)-1},$

which can be proved by induction.

Comment: Thank you Ana, how do you solve for $a_n= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-2} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-3}+ \cdots +\frac{1}{2}+1 = \frac{(1/2)^{n}-1}{(1/2)-1},$? I can imagine how you write out the sequence, but I'm lost when it comes to getting it to the fraction at the end

Comment: You just need to use the identity 
$x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-1}+\cdots +x+1)$,
for $x=1/2$.